# Bug in bundle children product price calculation

Tags: magento-1.8, price, bundled-product, bundle

I have a bundle with 2 simple product in it.

On the bundle product page, i click on "Add to cart". The cart sidebar resume show the quantity and the ATI price of the bundle.
If i "Add to cart" another time, the bundle price in the cart sidebar is now ET price * 2.
As a result the total cart price in the sidebar is : quantity * ( ET price * 2 )

Then i add to cart the same bundle with another option, the prices in the cart sidebar are now Ok.

The bug is only present in the cart sidebar, when i go the index checkout cart page (checkout/cart/), all the prices are ok.

Do you have any idea why this happen, or do you know how can i force the bundle product to recalculate it's prices ?

Comment: "ET"? And, do you have any customizations installed which relate to minicart or products?

Comment: ET = excluding taxes. The following modules are installed : solicolissimo, bundleoptions. But i see nothing which can interfere in the workflow

Comment: "bundleoptions" sounds relevant...

Comment: "bundleoptions" is only in charge to add image to the bundle sub-products

Comment: You never know. The best way to find it out is to disable installed modules and see if it changes. Also try if it's different with the default theme